# TableView can't do segue when TableViewCell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I come here to ask for help for a small problem that is occurring in the development of this application.

I have little experience with Swift, and I’m writing some code to learn more. I have this application that has in the initial screen a set of buttons that redirects to different pages and features.

The button called "Table View (CH Cantons)" redirects to a new view, which contains a TableView that show us three things:

- Canton emblem or coat of arms
- The Canton, as title : Ex: ZH - Zurich
- The area of specific canton

When a canton is selected the application should forward to a new page and show details about that particular canton, but this is not happening despite my efforts to solve the problem. Is TableView required to be in the Main View / Main Page?

[image]

Bellow is the connection with the Navigation controller

[image]

The code that generates the Table View

```
let cantonsData = ["AG - Aargau","BE - Bern","GE - Geneve","GR -  Graubunden","JU - Jura","LU - Lucern","NE - Neuchâtel","SG - Sankt Gallen","TG - Thurgau","TI - Ticino","UR - Uri","VD - Vaud","VS - Valais","ZH - Zurich","AI - Appenzell \n Innerrhoden","AR - Appenzell \n Ausserrhoden","SH - Schaffhausen","BL - Basel \n Landschaft","BS - Basel","SO - Solothurn","FR - Fribourg","ZG - Zug","GL - Glarus","NW - Nidwald","OW - Obwald", "SZ - Schwyz"]
    
    let area = ["Area (km2): 1404 km2","Area (km2): 5,960 km2","Area (km2): 1,792 km2","Area (km2): 7,105 km2","Area (km2): 839 km2","Area (km2): 1,494 km2","Area (km2): 802 km2 ","Area (km2): 2031 km2","Area (km2): 992 km2","Area (km2): 2812 km2","Area (km2): 1077 km2","Area (km2): 3212 km2","Area (km2): 5224 km2","Area (km2): 1729 km2","Area (km2): 172 km2","Area (km2): 243 km2","Area (km2): 298 km2","Area (km2): 518 km2","Area (km2): 37 km2","Area (km2): 790 km2","FR - Fribourg","ZG - Zug","GL - Glarus","NW - Nidwald","OW - Obwald", "SZ - Schwyz"]
    
    override var modalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationStyle {
        get { .fullScreen }
        set { assertionFailure("Shouldnt change that ") }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
        self.title = "CH Cantons / CH Kantons"
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        let nibName = UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableViewCell")
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cantonsData.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        
        cell.commonInit("CH-\(indexPath.item+1)", title: cantonsData[indexPath.item], sub: area[indexPath.item])
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 180
    }
```

function responsible for opening new page when a cell of table view is selected

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TableViewCH", bundle: nil)
        if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController{
            vc.img = UIImage(named: cantonsData[indexPath.item])!
            vc.canton = cantonsData[indexPath.row]
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
        
    }
```

I've tried another one but cannot solve the problem

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: cell)
    }
```

Comment: It seems you’r presenting tableView modally, so it’s not having a navigation stack to work with, hence you can’t push a controller. You can google about to push to new screen while presenting modally, that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TableViewCH", bundle: nil)
        if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController{
            vc.img = UIImage(named: cantonsData[indexPath.item])!
            vc.canton = cantonsData[indexPath.row]
            let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            nav.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
            self.present(nav, animation: true)
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: It works. Tanks a lot Arnab Ahamed Siam

Answer (score 0):

As other people have mentioned, you're presenting your screen modally (this means that it acts more as a popover and has no ViewController Stack). To fix this I would try going into the Storyboard file and selecting the `NavigationController` and selecting `presentation` near the bottom of the properties, change this to `over current context`